# what's the meaning of Symbols in PHP

Tags: php, yii

I have some newbie questions, but I can't easily search for those operators using google therefore hope somebody can help me with.

1. What is the operator :: used for?
2. Is there a different between "" and '' for string
3. I saw \exception, what is \ used for?

Comment: You can use [Symbolhound](http://symbolhound.com/?q=PHP+::+operator) instead of Google when searching for language tokens.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. What is the operator :: used for?

It's the [scope resolution operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php).

> 2. Is there a different between "" and '' for string

Yes. [Double quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) allow interpolation and special characters such as `\n`. Single quotes don't treat the string special.

> 3. I saw \exception, what is \ used for?

`\` is the [namespace operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php).

Answer (score 1):

1.Sometimes it is useful to refer to functions and variables in base classes or to refer to functions in classes that have not yet any instances. `The :: operator` is being used for this.

Refer:http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

2.

```
Single quoted
```

The simplest way to specify a string is to enclose it in single quotes (the character ').

```
Double quoted
```

If the string is enclosed in double-quotes ("), PHP will interpret more escape sequences for special characters.

Refer:http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

3.Answer is here [Importing classes and namespaces in PHP: What difference does a leading backslash make?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849279/importing-classes-and-namespaces-in-php-what-difference-does-a-leading-backslas)