# Facebook PHP SDK 4.0: using classes in subsites

Tags: php, facebook

I think this is very simple for many of you, but in the moment I got stuck with this. I have the following part of code:

header.php

```
include "facebook/autoload.php";

use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
```

test.php

```
include "header.php";
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url);
```

Why do I always get this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'FacebookRedirectLoginHelper' not found in test.php on line

I thought when I include a PHP file, classes can also be used. But in this case not, why? I think I do not understand how this autoload and use works, so I would be happy for some explanation.

Comment: Classes yeas, but I think that does not apply for the namespaces. If you could copy the `use` line from header in the test.php and check again.

Comment: Yeah this works! I must add this use line in every php file then????

Comment: Yes, that tells the script that the class `FacebookRedirectLoginHelper` is in that namespace and not in the global one. Alternatively you could use `$helper = new \Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url);` which is perfectly valid on its own, but you will end up wit too long lines in some cases.

Comment: but why this use command does not inherit the class namespace in the test.php? I do not understand that. Where is the advantage here?

Comment: see my answer for additional info. If I missed something let me know so I could update/clarify/improve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP does not inherit the namespaces nor the use statements of included/required files. This is intentional as otherwise if you include 2 files using a class aliased the same way you will get errors and you might not need all those classes in firs place.

If a class requires a namespace it has to have `use` statement defined with the full namespace to the particular class they need. Except in the cases where there might be aliasing. For example if you have:

```
// file1.php
use \My\Cool\LogWriter as Writer;
```

and

```
// file2.php
use \My\Cool\FileWriter as Writer;
```

Now both classes are accessible as `Writer`.

```
// test.php
require 'file1.php';
require 'file2.php';
```

In which case if you don't declare which class from which space you want this will give nasty error that class `Writer` is defined, which is true, but it is also true that the two classes are 2 separate ones.

For more information on namespaces in PHP5 see (http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php).

As a side note:

- Every file, if not `namespace` declaration is provided is considered in the global namespace.
- If a `use` is without leading slash the namespace might be considered relative to the current. (unsure but I think it depends on the autoloader?) (Reference here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4879615/1747193)